# How do you use variables in a regression formula in R?

Tags: r, regression

How do you use a variable in a regression formula?

For example, using the 'Animals' dataset (in MASS), the following works fine:

```
data(Animals)
model <- lm(body ~ brain, data = Animals)
```

But what I want to do is:

```
data(Animals)
x <- "body"
y <- "brain"
model <- lm(x ~ y, data = Animals)
```

This obviously doesn't work, but I can't figure out what I need to do. Ultimately, I'm trying to put the formula inside a loop and have it run something different each time.

Sorry if the answer is very obvious - I've searched but I can't solve it.

Many thanks

Comment: you can use `lm(paste0(x, "~", y), data = Animals)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make a proper formula from your character values. The easiest way in this case is the `reformulate()` function

```
reformulate(y,x)
# body ~ brain
```

then you can use this in your `lm()` call

```
lm(reformulate(y,x), data = Animals)
# 
# Call:
# lm(formula = reformulate(y, x), data = Animals)
# 
# Coefficients:
# (Intercept)        brain  
#  4316.32258     -0.06594
```

Comment: Is there any difference from `lm(formula(paste0(y,'~',x)),data=Animals)`?

Comment: `reformulate` makes it easier to use a vector of terms: `reformulate(c("var1","var2"),"respvar")` and has options for including intercepts. (but basically it just does the pasting for you).

Answer (score 1):

Use `get` function

```
lm(get(x) ~ get(y), data = Animals)
```

Comment: assuming you don't need to do anything like `predict()` from the model later (I'm assuming that's not `predict()` safe?)